# nestJs cors origin response always return wildcard ' * '

Tags: reactjs, cors, nestjs

i'm facing CORS issue between react (http://localhost:3000) and nestJs  (http://localhost:4000)
I added the `credentials: true` to both front and back as i'm going to work with secured cookies.

Here the backend nestJs side:

```
origin: (origin: any, callback: any) => {
  if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
    callback(null, true);
  } else {
    callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
  }
},
credentials: true,
methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS',
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
```

and here the frontend React:

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
 timeout: 1000 * 60 * 5,
 withCredentials: true,
 headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
 });
```

find attached screenshots from my browser after attempting my login request:

[image]

**Console CORS wildcard error:**

[image]

We can see that the response have " * " wildcard, but should not be.
Thanks !

Comment: 1. Drop all those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers from your request; they don't belong there. 2. `app.enableCors({origin: allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"], credentials: true})` would likely be sufficient.

Comment: You should take the time to read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: It is the same error with this configuration, all unnecessary conf you mentionned above was assed for testing ans debugging purposes, because i thought my error came from this

Comment: Now that you know all of this was cruft, you should update the code in your question to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please do provide a proper https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It could be that some intermediary (as opposed to your Express server itself) adds this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. Check what happens if you get rid of all of your CORS config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the error, it's because we cant have app.enableCors() and cors: true in the bootstrap function co-existing. the cors: true from bootstrap will override all responses headers.

```
async function bootstrap() {
**cors: true**
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    logger: ['error', 'warn', 'log', 'debug', 'verbose'],
  });
```